# How to dump png to stdout?

Tags: r, graphics, png, stdout

```
#pdf('/dev/stdout')
png('/dev/stdout')
plot(1:10, 1:10)
dev.off()
```

The above code works for pdf, but doesn't work for png.

```
$ lr -e 'source("main.R");'
Error in dev.off() :
  QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file '/dev/stdout'
```

How to dump png output to stdout?

Comment: I couldn't get either to work - the PDF didn't produce the error, but it also didn't seem to generate the pdf in /dev/stdout